# What does ~ mean in pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto, xml.etree

I am trying to use a pywinauto script, and it contains the character '~', such as

```
app.ModemSimulator.TypeKeys("%fc{ESC}")
app.ModemSimulator.TypeKeys("%fo~")
```

Could I get an explanation for what the ~ character means?

It may just mean ~, or possibly the syntax for the next key to press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) is simply an alias for <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `TypeKeys()`. It's just easier than typing `{ENTER}`.